# Find corrupted files on a partially recovered ext4

Tags: linux, data-recovery, ext4, ddrescue, fsck

I have **hard disk that was damaged** by impact when it was running. The disk had 6 partitions and some unallocated space too. After the impact, 3 partitions appear to be fine and I am able to read/write to them normally with a decent speed and filesystem checks don't fail either. But there was a **40 GiB ext4 partition** on the disk that has become partially unreadable after this incident.

This partition had about **8GB of free space**. There was a Linux distro installed on this partition and its `/home` was not on a separate partition. So all the user, OS and application data is in this single partition.

#### What have I tried

Initially I tried using the `dd` command in Linux to copy data from the damaged partition to another partition on another disk. But it kept failing multiple times giving read errors, and I had to resume it again manually, after adjusting the `skip` and `seek` options.

```
dd if=/dev/sdc4 of=/dev/sda2 bs=2M conv=notrunc status=progress iflag=noatime oflag=noatime seek=X skip=X
```

Although this was working (slowly), it was a painful process, and so I gave up.

On further reading, I found the [**GNU ddrescue**](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) tool and the [DDRescue-GUI](https://www.hamishmb.com/html/changelogs.php?program_name=ddrescue-gui) built on top of it, and decided to give it a try.

On the first day, in about 6-8 hours, I was able to recover 37+ GiB of data from this partition, running DDRescue-GUI multiple times (whenever I had free time) starting the recovery process from the beginning and the end alternately using the same log file. (I never got enough time to let it run in one stretch till completion)

On the second day, the recovery process happened quite slowly and at the end of the day, I am left with a **pending block of about 400 MB size** between the 2 GiB and 3 GiB mark of this partition. The bad sector count in the DDRescue output is still 0, but it takes enormous amount of time to read the data in this region, and the progress is less than 30MB after waiting for over 6 hours. I have tried running in both, forward and backward directions, and the speed of recovery is the same. Also, the non-trimmed counter in the DDRescue output has reached about 27MiB.
I understand that this particular pending portion of the disk is severly damaged, and hence its recovery is taking a lot of time.

#### The question

Unwilling to wait any longer, I would like to know if there is any way to get the **list of files that are incomplete, missing or unrepairable** in the current partially recovered ext4 partition?
For example, can `fsck.ext4` with certain options produce this list along with the **full paths** to the files?

So, if I find that the broken files are not useful to me, I can reinstall the OS and software and start using the recovered partition normally.

#### Additional question

Can I adjust DDRescue's reading interval so that it quickly skips over difficult-to-read sectors and I am able to further minimise the pending block of 400 MB without waiting for several days?

Comment: I found a [related similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/239439) but it seems to be for macOS, and the answers don't have anything specific for ext4.